# Run async task for 1 min in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to run my async task for few minutes and stop if it completes the work before time. Can I achieve this ? if yes, then how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

```
AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.)
```

So you might not want to use an `AsyncTask` to achieve this effect.